# Building Boost for Android on OSX result in empty librairies

Tags: android, android-studio, boost

I am trying to build boost on MacOS for Android.
I am using the [Build-for-Android](https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android) github tutorial.
I am on High Sierra and building boost 1.67 using NDK r16b.

I can succesfully build it using the following command:

> ./build-android.sh --arch=armeabi-v7a -with-libraries=system,thread
>   ~/android/android-ndk-r16b

My problem is the archive files are generated, they are malformed.
Running nm on them returns:

> nm libboost_thread.a
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm:
>   libboost_thread.a(/) The end of the file was unexpectedly encountered

So I went back and looked at the logs I had when building them and I've seen two things:

I got a bunch of these:

> boost_1_67_0/tools/build/src/user-config.jam:70: Unescaped special
>   character in argument
>   $(AndroidNDKRoot)/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/${PlatformOS}-x86_64

and finally when the archive file is generated, I get this:

> clang-darwin.archive
>   ../build/build/armeabi-v7a/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-darwin-armeabiv7a/release/link-static/target-os-android/threading-multi/libboost_system-clang-darwin-mt-a32-1_67.a warning:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib:
>   warning for library:
>   ../build/build/armeabi-v7a/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/clang-darwin-armeabiv7a/release/link-static/target-os-android/threading-multi/libboost_system-clang-darwin-mt-a32-1_67.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library
>   define global symbols)

Anyone has experience with this ?!
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I haven't figured out what's causing the issue, but precompiled libraries for Android can be found at https://github.com/dec1/Boost-for-Android

Comment: I had similar errors where my static libs contained "/" achieves that were empty. Issue was fixed by using target specific ranlib. Previously I used ranlib that is installed in the system. So if you using toolchain/SDK, ensure you use ranlib from that toolchain/SDK and not a system one.